# How do I get non-aggregated batch statistics with tf.keras.callbacks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model using the keras `model.fit()` method. This method returns a history object which contains loss values for each epoch - however I would like to have loss values for each individual batch.

Looking online I have found suggestions to use a custom callback class with an `on_batch_end(self, logs={})` method. The problem is that this method only gets passed *aggregated* statistics that get reset each epoch. I would like to have *individual* statistics for each batch.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback#on_train_batch_end

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easily with a custom training loop, where you can just append a list with the loss value of every batch.

```
train_loss_per_train_batch.append(loss_value.numpy())
```

Here's how to do all of it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load('iris', split='train', as_supervised=True)

train = ds.take(125).shuffle(16).batch(4)
test = ds.skip(125).take(25).shuffle(16).batch(4)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])


loss_object = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)


def compute_loss(model, x, y, training):
  out = model(x, training=training)
  loss = loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=out)
  return loss


def get_grad(model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = compute_loss(model, x, y, training=True)
    return loss, tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)


optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

verbose = "Epoch {:2d} Loss: {:.3f} TLoss: {:.3f} Acc: {:.2%} TAcc: {:.2%}"

train_loss_per_train_batch = list()

for epoch in range(1, 25 + 1):
    train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    train_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
    test_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    test_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

    for x, y in train:
        loss_value, grads = get_grad(model, x, y)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        train_acc.update_state(y, model(x, training=True))
        train_loss_per_train_batch.append(loss_value.numpy())

    for x, y in test:
        loss_value, _ = get_grad(model, x, y)
        test_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        test_acc.update_state(y, model(x, training=False))

    print(verbose.format(epoch,
                         train_loss.result(),
                         test_loss.result(),
                         train_acc.result(),
                         test_acc.result()))
```

Comment: as stated in the question, `on_train_batch_end` does not get individual batch statistics, only *aggregated* ones for all batches up until the current one.

Comment: I can find another way to do it, but could back up that statement? I can't find it in the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback#on_train_batch_end
It says so in the table describing the function parameters

Comment: I guess you should go for a custom training loop then (see updated answer)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to avoid that - oh well. Still thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The loss for the current batch can be calculated from the provided average loss as follows:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

class CustomCallback(Callback):
    ''' This callback converts the average loss (default behavior in TF>=2.2)
        into the loss for only the current batch.
    '''
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.previous_loss_sum = 0

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        # calculate loss of current batch:
        current_loss_sum =  (batch + 1) * logs['loss']
        current_loss = current_loss_sum - self.previous_loss_sum
        self.previous_loss_sum = current_loss_sum

        # use current_loss:
        # ...
```

This code can be added to any custom callback that needs the loss for the current batch instead of the average loss.

Also, if you are using Tensorflow 1 or TensorFlow 2 version <= 2.1, then do not include this code in your callback, as in those versions the current loss is already provided, instead of the average loss.